# how to find a list of available parameters for manetRouter in omnet.ini file

Tags: c, omnet++

I created a network of 10 hosts in omnet++ version, type of hosts is ManetRouter. I want a network in which 5 hosts run AODV and other hosts run DSDV routing protocols.

I am not sure how I can do it. Firstly, I don't know how to find available parameters in omnet.ini file for each module and their possible values.

Secondly, I don't know how I can determine the boundary for position and movement of nodes, for example in an 300*300 square area, I want to put 5 hosts in 150*150 on the left and other hosts on the right side of square. In addition, their movements only should limited to that 150*150 area.

Thirdly, the following code make a error in my omnet.ini file:

```
*.host[0..4].routingProtocolType="Aodv"
*.host[5..9].routingProtocolType="Dsdv"
```

I do appreciate it if you help me.

Comment: I've added the omnet++ tag, since that is relevant to this question.  That said, you'll need to provide a lot more information, preferably full source, for what you're doing.  As written, this question is pretty much impossible to answer, since we can't identify exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I agree, posing three questions in a single entry in SO is a no-no. You should formulate your questions in a way that they could be answered in a way the is either acceptable or not. I encourage you to split this into at least three question. And finally stating that something "make an error" does no help much if someone wants to help you. At least state the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As for the title and first part of your question:

Look in the corresponding NED files for parameters and documentation. NED files are used to describe the topology and parameters of the network.